# Plot on a 2D grid a spherically symmetric function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compute a spherically symmetric function on a 2D grid. The simple solution that I came up with is the following:

```
Grid_side = 10
N_pix = 100

function = lambda r : 1.0 / r**2.0

grid_x = np.linspace(-Grid_side, Grid_side, N_pix)
grid_y = np.linspace(-Grid_side, Grid_side, N_pix)

SphericallySymmetric_function_GRID = np.zeros((N_pix, N_pix))

for i in range(N_pix):

        for j in range(N_pix):

            SphericallySymmetric_function_GRID[i,j] = function(np.sqrt(grid_x[i]**2.0 + grid_y[j]**2.0))
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do the following, taking advantage of Numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to iterate if the function works with arrays, and you use broadcasting to populate a grid:

```
def fn(X,Y):
    r = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
    return 1/r**2
fn(grid_x[:,None], grid_y[None,:])
```

`np.meshgrid` and `np.mgrid` (or `np.ogrid`) can also be used to form the `X,Y` grid.

```
fn(*np.meshgrid(grid_x, grid_y))
fn(*np.ogrid[-Grid_side:Grid_side:N_pix*1j, -Grid_side:Grid_side:N_pix*1j])
```

Look up their docs, and practice.  Practice with simple things like `grid_x[:,None]+grid_y` as well.

Comment: I think it's clearer to write `np.newaxis` instead of `None`.

Comment: Do you also like it in this slicing notation: `grid_x[slice(np.newaxis, -1, np.newaxis)]`?  :)

Comment: No, that would be misleading since a new axis is not created. `grid_x[:-1]` would be better.